# Polyfills core-js versions

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, polyfills, ecmascript-2016

Due to a problem with Internet Explorer 11 and ES7 `array.includes()` function i had to import `core-js/es7/array` in the `polyfills.ts`. I have noticed, that there is already a `core-js/es6/array`.

My question is, does the `es7/array` includes the polyfills for the older version `es6/array` (and below)? Can I remove the `es6/array` or do I need both of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After comparing the [core-js/es6/object.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2/es6/object.js) with the [core-js/es7/object.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2/es7/object.js) it is clear that the ES6 polyfill indeed adds only methods introduced in ES6 and this is not covered by the ES7 polyfill. That one only adds methods introduced in ES7.

Comment: So should it be removed or not??

Comment: It should not be removed

Comment: Doing the same. includes function was not working in my react app and started working after adding import 'core-js/es7/array'. i kept both es6 and es7